# Setting A Form's backColor to a ARGB value

Tags: c#, winforms, hex, rgb

I've been working on a simple HEX to RGB (and vise versa) translator. Essentially the user can input the HEX value as a string and the textbox above will display the conversion. In addition to this, I would like the background of the form to change to the corresponding color input - though this is where the problem lies. The background color does not change.

To do so, I have this

```
        Color rgbValue = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
        String conversion = rgbValue.ToString();

        Form converterForm = new Form();
        converterForm.BackColor = rgbValue;

        RGB_Box.Text = String.Format("rgb({0},{1},{2})", red, green, blue);
```

I've stepped through the code with a fixed HEX input of #E9967A; the values of variables are as follows: blue(122), green(150), red(233). The value of converterForm.BackColor is "Name=ffe9967a, ARGB=(255,233,150,122)".

Is there a way that the value for the BackColor should be modified so that the color can be correctly interpreted?

Comment: You never show the `converterForm` with `converterForm.Show();` so how can you tell if the colour didn't change?

Comment: @Equalsk Doing so creates a new form (i.e two are displayed), however the new form has the correct background color.

Comment: If you want to change the existing form then change `this.BackColor`

Comment: @Equalsk Interesting - that worked. Could you write your comment as an answer and I will mark it? Further explanation would be appreciated, I'm not sure why that would worked over the previous. Thanks :)

Comment: @LukeIsitt: You're making a new form, changing its background, then ignoring it.  Why do you expect that to do anything?

Comment: @SLaks I've just recently switched from C++-CLI to C# - creating new instances is a very new concept to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some more reading into C# and object orientated programming to fully understand what's happening.

In short when you use the [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) keyword you create a brand new form, separate to the one you already have. You change the colour of this second form and never show it, so of course it looks like nothing happened.

The [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) keyword specifies the existing instance of the form.